# 「変数名 + ブロック」の書式名称が分かりません

Tags: swift3

いつもお世話になっております。

以下のコードはどのような書式名なのか分かりますでしょうか？
クロージャーの初期化でもないようで、（=がない為）
調べても分からなかったのでご質問させて頂きました。

```
var value: String? { return "abc" }
print(value!)  // abc
```

よろしくお願い致します。

Answer (score 1):

すみません。
自己解決しました。

プロパティのget,setの記述方法で、getを省略した記述になります。
この場合、読み取り専用となります。

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Properties.html

```
var value: String? { return "abc" }
print(value!)
//value = "ABC"  ...読み取り専用なのでエラーする
```

ありがとうございました。